# using readPassword() method

Tags: java

```
 import java.io.*;  
 class ReadPasswordTest
   {  
    public static void main(String args[])
    {  
     Console c=System.console();  
     System.out.println("Enter password: ");  
     char[] ch=c.readPassword();  
     String pass=String.valueOf(ch);//converting char array into string  
     System.out.println("Password is: "+pass);  
    }  
   }
```

My question is...why can't I directly store my password from the console in a string and display it directly...instead of storing it in a char array..converting it into a string and displaying it.when I do the latter way I get some special characters displaying.